# How to catch and diagnose Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

This issue comes up in my server and I'm not able to catch where is it coming from, how can I track an issue like this and what might be the cause?

I have bugsnag setup in my server + newRelic and both don't give me information about this issue.

I'm running my application on a Ubuntu 18.04.5 using nginx.

Also is it normal that when this issue comes all the request on the server goes into Gateway timeout.

````
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
^[[41m^[[30mfail^[[39m^[[22m^[[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.ReadAsyncInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
^[[41m^[[30mfail^[[39m^[[22m^[[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.```
````

Answer (score 2):

Check out this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23949. Especially this comment:

> This exception seems to be thrown when a client aborts mid-request.

You can ignore this error by including the following MVC [exception filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-filters):

```cs
if (ex is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException && 
    ex.Message == "Unexpected end of request content.")
{
    // "Unexpected end of request content."
    // Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.CoreStrings.BadRequest_UnexpectedEndOfRequestContent
    // ignore this
}
```